# Question about answering

Tags: responses

Scenario 1

> person 1 - Have you ran?
>   person 2 - I haven't ran.
>   person 3 - I didn't run.

Scenario 2

> person 1 - Did anyone salt that pork?
>   person 2 - I haven't salted that pork.
>   person 3 - I didn't salt that pork.

I'm confused at which to use when people ask in the form of person 1 above. In scenario 1, who is correct between person 2 and person 3? Also scenario 2, who is correct? If someone asks a question in Did. Should I answer in Did or didn't instead of have or haven't?  And Vice/versa.

I hope all that points out what I'm confused about.

Comment: I think what you're asking is which answer between Person 2 and Person 3 is correct?

Comment: @Andrew yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit) The correct perfect of "run" is *run* not *ran*.  However, it is not uncommon when talking about *the sport* of *running* to instead use *ran*.

> Have you **ran** the Boston Marathon?  It's difficult to even qualify.

Because this is a specialized use and not universally accepted, in this answer I will use *have run* instead.

There is a difference between "have you run?" and "did you run?"  The use of the present perfect tense implies a relationship between the time the action took place and now.  So using it in a question implies an unspoken "yet", or "before this moment".

> Have you eaten dinner?  (= Have you eaten dinner **yet**)

Also there is a reasonable expectation that the activity could have or should have been done before now.

> Have you called her back (yet)?  It's been three days!
>
> Have you prepared lunch (yet)?  It's after 1pm and I'm starving!
>
> Have you brushed your teeth (yet)?  It's almost bedtime!

So asking "have you run" is a little strange unless you *expected* the person would have been running before now.

The response is usually "Yes, I have" or "No, I have not".  On the other hand, if someone asks a question using the simple past such as:

> Did you call her back?
>
> Did you make lunch?
>
> Did you brush your teeth?

You would normally match the verb tense: "Yes, I did", or "No, I did not".

Note that this isn't the only use of the present perfect tense.  It can also indicate an existing or ongoing condition, including some kind of life experience:

> Have you been running?  You look sweaty.
>
> Have you been to Japan?  I heard that you lived there when you were in your twenties.
>
> Have you been sick?  You don't look so good.

Again, the answer would be "Yes, I have" or "No, I haven't" to match the verb tense of the question.

Answer (score 0):

person 1 - Have you ran?   should be: Did you run? / Have you  run?

person 2 - I haven't ran.  should be: I have not run. / I didn't run.

person 3 - No it's I didn't run. should be: No, I didn't run. / No, I haven't run yet.

person 1 - Did anyone salt that pork? yes

person 2 - I haven't salted that pork. yes

person 3 - I didn't salt that pork. yes  these three are correct.

Now we need someone to tell us what the grammar is.